# Problem translating MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration

We're using Trac for issue tracking. I migrated it from MySQL to PostgreSQL, but some of the ticket queries no longer work.

In the below, all I did this far is replace `IFNULL()` with `COALESCE()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` with `TO_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP`

I don't know what the error means. The query worked just fine in MySQL, and I'm not sure, after looking at pages discussing differences between it and PostgreSQL, what the problem is (I also don't know what to replace the SEC_TO_TIME line with, but removing that line doesn't fix the error).

```
SELECT IFNULL(CONCAT('Component ', t.component), 'Total for all Components') AS __group__,
    (CASE
      WHEN t.id > 0 THEN (CASE t.status WHEN 'closed' THEN 'color: #777; background: #ddd; border-color: #ccc;' END)
      ELSE 'font-weight: bold'
    END) AS __style__,
    t.id AS ticket,
    IF(t.id > 0, t.summary, 'Total') AS summary,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IF(w.endtime, w.endtime, TO_TIMESTAMP(NOW())::TIMESTAMP) - w.starttime)) AS total
  FROM ticket t
  INNER JOIN work_log w
  WHERE t.id = w.ticket
  GROUP BY t.component, t.id, t.summary, t.status
  WITH ROLLUP HAVING IFNULL(id, -1) = -1 OR (t.summary IS NOT NULL AND t.status IS NOT NULL);

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 11:  WHERE t.id = w.ticket
```

**Edit:** I tried changing the `WHERE` to `ON`, and that seemed to fix that error; however, I don't know if this is the correct solution. Also, now I get an error with the `"WITH ROLLUP HAVING"` part. What's the way to do it in PostgreSQL?

Also, I don't know what to replace `SEC_TO_TIME` with above, or the `SUM` / `IF` combo (as `IF()` is MySQL only--if I swap to `CASE`, do I need to test separately for 0 and null?). Using TO_CHAR as per http://www.verious.com/qa/sec-to-time-function-in-postgre-sql/ doesn't work because the minutes are always zero with the code given there (i.e. 90 seconds ends up as 00:00:30...)

**Edit 2:** What I'm trying to end up with, which was the case with MySQL:

[image]

**Edit 3:** Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name and efesar, I've ended up with the following working query:

```
WITH base AS (
  SELECT t.component AS component, t.status AS status, t.id AS ticket, t.summary AS summary,
      SUM((CASE WHEN w.endtime > 0 THEN w.endtime ELSE CAST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp) AS bigint) END) - w.starttime) * INTERVAL '1 second' AS total
    FROM ticket t
    INNER JOIN work_log w
    ON t.id = w.ticket
    GROUP BY t.component, t.id, t.summary, t.status
)
SELECT CONCAT('Component ', component) AS __group__,
    (CASE status WHEN 'closed' THEN 'color: #777; background: #ddd; border-color: #ccc;' END) AS __style__,
    ticket, summary, total
  FROM base
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('Component ', component) AS __group__,
  'font-weight: bold' as __style__, null, 'Total', SUM(total)
  FROM base
  GROUP BY __group__
UNION ALL
SELECT 'All Components' AS __group__, 'font-weight: bold' as __style__, null, 'Total', SUM(total)
  FROM base
ORDER BY __group__, ticket
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT coalesce(CONCAT('Component ', t.component), 'Total for all Components') AS __group__,
       CASE
          WHEN t.id > 0 THEN CASE t.status WHEN 'closed' THEN 'color: #777; background: #ddd; border-color: #ccc;' END
          ELSE 'font-weight: bold'
        END AS __style__,
        t.id AS ticket,
        case when t.id > 0 then t.summary else 'Total' end AS summary,
        SUM( coalesce(w.endtime, current_timestamp) - w.starttime) AS total
FROM ticket t
  INNER JOIN work_log w ON t.id = w.ticket
GROUP BY t.component, t.id, t.summary, t.status
```

The `sum()` will sum up the difference in milliseconds between `endtime` and `starttime` not sure what the intention behind that is.

I'm not entirely sure what the rollup does, but something along the lines:

```
with base_data as (
   ... the above query goes here ...
)
select __group__, ticket, __style__, summary, total
from base_data
union all
select null, null, null, null, sum(total)
from base_data
group by __group__, ticket, __style__, summary
```

might get you started.

Comment: when the `GROUP BY` has 4 columns, the `ROLLUP` modifier will show 4 levels of aggregates. It will be a pain to write in Postgres (write the window functions and manage to get the same ordering in the end.)

Comment: @ypercube: a thanks. I hever used `rollup` (not even in Oracle) so I was just guessing

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so taking most of my comments and forming them into an answer:

1. PostgreSQL doesn't support JOIN conditions in the WHERE clause. Use an ON clause instead.
2. ROLLUP HAVING is typically replaced with [Window functions using the OVER clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html). I'm not an expert on the ROLLUP HAVING but I might be able to clarify the Window functions if you need.
3. Replace the IFNULL with the COALESCE function.
4. Replace the IF function with the CASE expression.
5. Try replacing the SEC_TO_TIME functions with a slightly different usage of the [AGE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-datetime.html) function. The AGE function returns INTERVALs which can be summed. Here is a [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/baf81/1).
6. In PG, you can subtract two TIMESTAMPs to get an INTERVAL (so endtime - starttime might return something like '42 days').

I hope that covers everything. I'll add updates as needed.

Comment: Postgres *does* support join conditions in the where clause, it just doesn't support an incomplete `JOIN` operator